vue 3 options api data accessibility
Is there a manner to access a vue option api.
assume the below code.
 import {visualization} from "../util/Visualization"
 export default {
      data:() =>({
               foo = ''
         })
      }
    }

is there a way to access 'foo' within the function visualization defined within 'visualization.js' , foo is also bound with <textarea v-model="foo" /> so basically modify the value of template element from an js method.
have searched extensively have a working example , from all i have tried , the only way i could do this is to access the element with getElementById , but this directly set the element bypassing the variables which breaks functionality.

You could import the variable/function into your Vue's Options API yes. More details are welcome here.

that does not work

You seem to need what is called "a single source of truth".
It could be a reactive object or a store. This single source of truth can be imported in as many places as you need (e.g: your component and visualisation) and, whenever one changes the value, it's updated everywhere it is being used.

Example with a reactive object:
myDataStore:
import { reactive } from 'vue'
export const myData = reactive({
  foo: 'bar'
})

Then, in as many places as you want:
import { myData } from './path/to/myDataStore'
// use (and modify) `myData.foo`

Whenever myData.foo receives a new value, all the places where it is used will be updated. myData.foo can also be used in v-model.

Example with store:
myDataStore:
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
export const useMyDataStore = defineStore('myData', {
  state: () => ({
    foo: 'bar'
  })
})

Then, in as many places as you want:
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
import { useMyDataStore } from './path/to/myDataStore'
const { foo } = storeToRefs(useMydataStore())

Now foo is a ref. You can use foo.value inside <script> and foo inside <template> (including v-model usage).
In Options API you use it as:

getter only:

  computed: {
    foo() { return useMyDataStore().foo }
  }


getter + setter:

  computed: {
    foo: {
      get() {
        return useMyDataStore().foo
      },
      set(val) {
        useMyDataStore().foo = val
      }
    }
  }


'data' is an options api object , its already reactive this , will not work.

@vuejscoder: The whole point of the answer is that you can't externalize data,  but you can externalize its contents: you have to move your foo outside of data, into an external reactive object. You can then consume it in your component using a computed foo() { return useMyDataStore().foo }

how will i bind to a template element if it is not a data member, also do you have an example of a vanilla .js file using 'computed' i need a working example
